# What is the best way to keep bugs out of the sukkah?

Tags: product-recommendation, sukkah, bugs, how-to

What is the best way to keep bugs, specifically mosquitoes, out of a sukkah on Yom Tov? I've looked into various candles, tiki torches, etc., but they won't last through both days of Yom Tov.

Comment: What is the best way to program... in the sukkah? What about in a sukkah on a boat (according to r Akiva that such a sukkah is kosher)?

Comment: Very related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10644/2

Comment: @DoubleAA, this is a perfectly valid how-to-implement-Judaism question. The set of issues presented by sukka architecture, "ke'ein taduru," mandated activities, Yom Tov, etc. with respect to flying pests may or may not be quite unique, but it's at least special and of special interest to observant Jews.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I agree with you, although I totally hear where Double AA is coming from. Given the (slightly) unique challenge Diaspora Jews face of maintaining any such solution over a duration of a two-day or even three-day Yom Tov, I think it's worthy of a question.

Comment: @Isaac It doesn't involve any Judaism expertise. We aren't trying to attract a bunch of entomologists. What about: My sukkah uses this kind of hinge. Should I secure it with a nail or a screw? What are the benefits and drawbacks of each?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I've explained how it does involve Judaism expertise, as does [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/19096/) about lighting, [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31017/) about flooring, [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4316/) about hardware, and [this one](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3/) about lifting. They are all examples of requests for practical advice that perhaps someone could give or be interested without being an observant Jew, but which observant Jews, thanks to their experience, are more likely to be able to provide or be interested in.

Comment: I disagree on this one and the hex nut one. They require no Jewish understanding of the situation. The others do utilize an understanding of the situation and expectations that only a Jew would have. Hence they require our experts.

Comment: @Scimonster -- I think this question deserves both tags, because the answer could be a technique OR a product. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

I use [mosquito barrier](http://www.mosquitobarrier.com/?gclid=CPz5pLSl1bkCFROZ4AodNkQAXQ) immediately prior to Sukkos and I have a mosquito free Sukkos.

Comment: How large is your sukkah, and how much do you use? What do you apply it to?

Comment: Also, does it smell?

Comment: @IsaacMoses: It is a very faint smell which does not bother me.

Answer (score 4):

we used dryer sheets taped to the inside of the walls. we labeled them annanei ha'kavod and they seemed to do a pretty good job keeping out both mosquitos and bees.

Here's some of [the science behind it](http://blogs.smithsonianmag.com/science/2010/12/dryer-sheets-as-bug-repellant/)

Answer (score 1):

We live on a farm, lots of bugs here... we use this in our Sukkah, as well as many other buildings.. :
http://reliableexterminators.ca/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=151

Answer (score 1):

Mosquito netting is effective, and is not a Chatzitzah between you and the Schach so long as it is hanging close to your body. (Don't support the Schach on the stuff...)

Though, that does give me a business idea...  Moskito Netting that is Kosher for Schach - ie Made out of non-woven spun cotton... I wonder if it could work...

Answer (score 1):

I was in a sukkah where the host had cut lemongrass growing in his garden, and spread it on the floor of the sukkah. I don't know if it was as effective as a citronella candle in discouraging mosquitoes. Also, lemongrass might only offgas the repellent for a certain number of hours, and be no more than a conversation piece after that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one thing you can do that will keeps bugs out of your sukkah. I wwould suggest a combination of all anti-bug technology

1. off candles or other similar candles that make a smell bugs don't like
2. torches (like candles but bigger.) probably best to have these by the entrance and not inside the sukkah
3. a bug zapper. these work great but can be a little annoying because of the sound. better to keep nearby the sukkah but not in it
4. lastly the distraction. the bugs really aren't there to "bug" you but because of the delicious dinner you are having. make them their own delicious dinner nearby but outside of the sukkah. For bugs sugar water works best. The sweet smells will lure them to the water and then they will drown in the water when they fly into it. There are also special bags and containers you can buy which are more effective. these have a hole at the top which allow the bugs in but not back out.

chag sameach

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/Print.asp?ClipID=964) I would recommend making one of [these](http://www.thriftyfun.com/tf22399231.tip.html) though I have not tried it myself.