# Hadassim with 3 leaves equally

Tags: product-recommendation, sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

My Hadassim (chut Hamakif AAA) grew roots.

For the first 1+year, the main one grew 3 leaves and the off-shoots (from where the leaves fell off) grew one leaf staggered up each twig. Now for 1+ years it grows 2 leaves next to each other but never 3.

I heard one can burn it and that encourages multiple leaves to grow next to each other?

What is that, or what else can be done?

Comment: I also heard about the burning idea, not sure this works. I think the professional hadassim growers just have large plantations where they expect some hadassim to have 2 leaves and some 3. May be worthwhile asking the RHS (https://www.rhs.org.uk/).

Comment: This is a horticultural question not a judaism question

Comment: @robev Should it be migrated to a different StackExchange?

Comment: The standard on this site puts this on topic. See: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31202/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-bugs-out-of-the-sukkah#comment80144_31202

Comment: @Yishai this one is better since it's something no non Jew would care or think about